# How do I execute commands on Karaf running inside Docker?

Tags: docker, apache-karaf

I'm setting up currently running Apache karaf inside a docker container. I have used the following code to create docker image.

```
FROM java:8-jdk
MAINTAINER mkroli
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV KARAF_VERSION=4.0.5

RUN wget http://apache.openmirror.de/karaf/${KARAF_VERSION}/apache-karaf-${KARAF_VERSION}.tar.gz; \
mkdir /opt/karaf; \
tar --strip-components=1 -C /opt/karaf -xzf apache-karaf-${KARAF_VERSION}.tar.gz; \
rm apache-karaf-${KARAF_VERSION}.tar.gz; \
mkdir /deploy; \
sed -i 's/^\(felix\.fileinstall\.dir\s*=\s*\).*$/\1\/deploy/' /opt/karaf/etc/org.apache.felix.fileinstall-deploy.cfg

VOLUME ["/deploy"]
EXPOSE 1099 8101 44444
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/karaf/bin/karaf"]
```

My Docker container has the Karaf up and running. Once the Karaf is started I need to run the basic commands inside karaf(Ex. feature:list, feature:install) so that I can install my features/bundles and list them.

1. I have tried running commands in an interactive shell, but the problem is I cannot come back to the docker shell, if I come back the Karaf container gets stopped.

So how can I execute commands on Karaf running inside Docker?

Comment: did you try `docker exec -it container_id bash` and then launch your commands?  the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: and keep in mind that `docker run Karaf bash ` launches a new container, it does not get into your running Karaf container

Comment: If I do so by exec or run I can get into karaf shell, but if I try to get to docker shell I need to logout(which stops Karaf server) and the handle comes to docker container.

Answer (score 1):

change your dockerfile and add following

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/apache/karaf/bin/start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about ssh'ing into your docker-Karaf Image and issue the shell commands from there? But make sure you have that port for ssh exported:

```
EXPOSE 8081
```

Answer (score 0):

you should access to karaf from your host machine 8101 is the port used inside the container .
try this command to run the container in interactive mode

```
docker run -it -p 8101:8080 mkroli/karaf
```

you can run this container in backgroud using -d option .

Answer (score 0):

In Jean-Baptiste Onofré's Blog post, [Apache Karaf & Docker](http://blog.nanthrax.net/?p=839), he shows how to set up and run [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) inside a Docker container.

Create a container using [his build.sh script](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/assemblies/docker/build.sh) by running something like:

```
build.sh --from-release --karaf-version 4.2.7 --image-name karaf
```

Then, you can run the Karaf console in the container with:

```
docker-compose run karaf
```

[image]

Voila! :)